# Python regex substitution: separate backreference from digit

Tags: python, regex, backreference

In a regex replacement pattern, a backreference looks like `\1`.  If you want to include a digit after that backreference, this will fail because the digit is considered to be part of the backreference number:

```
# replace all twin digits by zeroes, but retain white space in between
re.sub(r"\d(\s*)\d", r"0\10", "0 1")
>>> sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
```

Substitution pattern `r"0\1 0"` would work fine but in the failing example back-reference `\1` is interpreted as `\10`.

How can the digit `'0'` be separated from the back-reference `\1` that precedes it?

Comment: what is going on here?

Comment: @segfolt He asked, and answered his own question - perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @segfolt florisla probably wanted to put a question and put the solution to it himself.

Comment: Ah ok I'm quite new in SO so I didn't know it was possible to do such a thing

Comment: I found the solution while I was typing out the question. So I used the 'Answer your own queston' checkbox.

Comment: I like both answers, so I upvoted both. Nice q/a!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using a backreference with a sequence number (`\1`), you can use named groups and the problem is solved:

```
# replace all twin digits by zeroes, but retain whitespace in between
re.sub(r"\d(?P<whitespace>\s*)\d", r"0\g<whitespace>0", "0 1")
>>> '0 0'
```

Turns out this trick is in fact described in the [documentation of re.sub](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer :) (I think there's a time limit though, I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: True, there's a 2-day time limit.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `\g<1>`, as mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: Typical case of not reading the docs thoroughly enough, thanks for that.